# Help with Draping an Image over a TIN in FME for viewing in MeshLab or Similar

Tags: fme-form, 3d-model, meshlab

I'm using FME to generate a TIN from a LiDAR point cloud, and everything is working except for draping an image over the resulting TIN.

I've read all the FME help pages, and checked out the examples that are easily googled.

I'm currently doing the following:

- Selecting the last-strike from the LiDAR point  cloud
- Generating a TIN
- Clipping an ECW to the area of interest
- Using an AppearanceStyler on the image, and then AppearanceSetter with the TIN going into the geometry port and the image into the appearance port
- Writing the result out to Collada and OBJ formats, as well as viewing the results in the inspector

The TIN is visible in MeshLab, and looks fine, but I can't get a texture (draped image) to show up! I can't see it in the Collada or OBJ files, and not in the inspector, so I think something is wrong in the workspace.

Anyone got a methodology that will work?

[image: Example of AppearanceSetter settings]

Comment: I'm assuming you've seen this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=edZeJLWDqiQ

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I went through that example here: http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/3D-Textured-Examples

Comment: Bit of a long shot (based on my memory of a similar problem) - have you tried using FaceReplacer between TINGenerator and AppearanceSetter?

Comment: Hey, @mKurowsKi, that worked! I didn't think it would, but it did!

Comment: Nice! glad to hear

Comment: Would you like to write it up briefly below and I'll get the bounty to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To paraphrase my initial suggestion in the comments section:

Looking at your workspace, it seems that inserting a FaceReplacer between TINGenerator and AppearanceSetter should do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the solution suggested by @mKurowsKi worked.

Adding a FaceReplacer between the TINGenerator and the AppearanceSetter means that the OBJ file, when opened in MeshLab has colour!

Very nice...

[image: draped imagery on OBJ file in Meshlab]

Comment: In that case, I think @mKurowsKi deserves the bounty.

Comment: Yep, well can @mKurowsKi please write it up briefly?

Comment: sure! just wrote it up below

Comment: I've used R packages RTriangle and rgl to do this stuff - the tricky part is the point-cloud processing - just did something dopey like a max within cell - , but everything else reasonably straightforward. Have you tried other free software workflows? i'm keen to use D3 for the vis ultimately.

Comment: Sorry, @mdsumner, I've only used FME for this. It saves a lot of hacking around with code! I'm not sure where I'd start to do this using open source tools.